# Real-time push config to an application on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have several EC2 instances running an application that I need to push config to in real-time. Each instance of the application needs to be able to get the most recent config when it comes up, and receive new configs with <500ms latency. Configs are only ~1kb. The servers running the application span multiple regions.

I've previously used Apache Zookeeper for this purpose, but I was wondering if there was a way to use a managed solution? The first thing that comes to mind is a hosted Amazon RDS PostgreSQL server with `NOTIFY/LISTEN` but that seems overkill?

Comment: Can you please expand your question to give more context. What are you configuring? Your EC2 instance?? Is EC2 acting as a file server for some kind of remote client? Something else? It's difficult to answer with the limited information you've given us. If you are just sending files to a remote device can you just upload to S3 and have it downloaded from there? S3 announced strong "read after write" consistency about a year ago https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/

Comment: Thanks @Tim! Have clarified. It's just an application running on the EC2 instances that needs the up-to-date config. And S3 would be fine, if we had a way to subscribe to a bucket with <500ms latency? Are there other options? PostgreSQL NOTIFY/LISTEN would probably be lower latency?

Comment: SNS latency is under 100ms. You might be able to push the config through SNS, or push a notification on SNS to be pulled from S3. You'll have to test to see if can happen under 500ms, that's an unusually tight timeframe. I wonder if re-architecting in some way could reduce the need for such a tight timeframe. https://betterdev.blog/aws-messaging-services-sqs-sns-kinesis-eventbridge/

Comment: Could also look at pushing the config via an SQS queue?